# How to download songs from SoundCloud (They're no longer providing API keys)

Tags: python, soundcloud

I want to create a Python script to download soundcloud playlists and sort them by genre and artist name, but it turns out that SoundCloud is no longer offering API keys. Can I still do that?
How can I obtain a client ID?

I thought that it's possible to download them with client ID
but how can I get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) and their [SoundCloud extractor](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/soundcloud.py)